# Unexpected < in JSON position 0 && Error: Missing S3 key - MERN App, Heroku

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, mern, image-upload

I combined both things in the title of the question because I believe they are related.

I have a MERN + Redux App which I deployed to Heroku.  The app is for an artist to upload his images, so I used multer to store the image files in the app/uploads/ directory while also saving the records in MongoDB Atlas Cloud storage.

This was fine, but of course Heroku's file storage is ephemeral, so I decided to use an S3 bucket for storage.

I figured out how to incorporate posting the images to the S3 bucket, but I did so via:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const upload = require('../../middleware/upload');     <<~~ multer diskStorage
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

// Commission model
const Commission = require('../../models/Commission');

// AWS Configuration
const ID = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
const SECRET = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.S3_BUCKET;
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET
});

const uploadFile = (imagename, imagedata) => {
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(imagedata);

  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: imagename,
    Body: fileContent
  };

  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(`File uploaded to S3 successfully: ${data.Location}`)
  });
};

// @route   POST /commissions
// @descrip Create a new commission
// @access  Private
router.route('/').post(upload.single('imageData'), authorize, (req, res) => {
  uploadFile(req.body.imageName, req.file.path);

  const newCommission = new Commission({
    imageName: req.body.imageName,
    imageData: req.file.path,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    price: req.body.price
  });

  newCommission.save()
    .then(commission => res.json(commission))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Create new commission failed: ${err}`));
});
```

That route was basically untouched except for the addition of the `upload` function.

Anyways, that worked as far as:

- posting a mongo document
- saving the file to my S3 bucket

But it didn't actually display anything from my bucket.  I suspected it was because, in my app/server.js file, I was still using:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

So I installed `s3-proxy` and, in my server.js wrote:

```
const s3Proxy = require('s3-proxy');
 
app.get('/media/*', s3Proxy({
  bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  overrideCacheControl: 'max-age=100000',
  defaultKey: 'index.html'
}));
```

This.. did nothing, seemingly.  So I tinked with the `prefix` option, putting the URL of my S3 bucket.
During my tinkering, and a few `localhost` page reloads, suddenly my documents were stuck in `loading` state.

I opened the devtools and in the `console` it reads

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

and in the `network` tab there are a number of errors, and they all say

```
Error: Missing S3 key
```

The app works (without the image functionality obviously) on Heroku/production, sans the Network tab errors, but locally this is broken.

I found solutions that were focused on possible code mistakes and typos, but I didn't make any.  I even reverted the changes back to when the app was absolutely working.

One solution I found suggested corruption took place within the node_modules somehow, so I completely deleted them and ran `npm i` again for a reset.

Didn't work, so I tried again but deleted `package-lock.json` as well.

I'm out of ideas.  "Missing S3 key" in an app that now has no connection to S3 (I uninstalled aws-sdk and s3-proxy packages, and removed the code)

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by clearing browser cache history.